# Connection.queries returns empty list

Tags: python, django, django-models

Not sure what's up.  DEBUG mode is set to be on, and everything else is working fine:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> connection.queries
[]
```

Nothing is added to `connection.queries`, even when I refresh a page that I know is doing queries..

Background: Using SQLite for the db, Django version 1.3.1, Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't get an entry in `connection.queries` in the shell when you refresh a page - that's not how it works. You'll get an entry when you perform a query in the shell.

If you want to see what your page is doing, you can dump connection.queries to the page output, or even better use the Django-debug-toolbar.